# Best JS framework for web and hybrid appsif I already do web design?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

We are starting new development on mobile devices. We want to do webapps (with strong offline behavior) and hybrid apps, and keep business logic the much as we can in JS.

After a long time googling around about [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), I am actually thinking that it is not what we need: we actually count with an incredible web designer, so we want to use his talent to create the screens. This go against JQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch philosofy, because is just what they do: UI interface.

So, if we want to use our own screens, is there any benefit in using JQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch for the business logic and/or back-end ? Wouldn't it be overkill and in the end worse in terms of performance ? Would it be too much work to do our own business/back-end framework (ajax, jsonp, localStorage, filesystem access, etc...).

The much I see, the most I think that the only think that I would need from Sencha Touch are transitions (Jquery Mobile ones are terrible)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of smaller frameworks that will provide you both with DOM manipulation and AJAX and local storage for being able to work offline.

- For DOM / Ajax / event handling:

  - Snack.js: http://snackjs.com/
  - xui: http://xuijs.com/
- For local persistence:

  - store.js: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js
  - Lawnchair: http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

They will do their part and stay out of your way to give your app the appearance you want.

Comment: We ended using multiple frameworks like xui, jquery (NO Touch nor UI),  and we're eavily using PhoneGap. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 2):

They are both **good framework choices** for building your web/mobile apps.

While the most **obvious** thing about JQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch is their UI (its the first bit you seen when you navigate to their examples), there is also a lot of useful framework stuff running in the background, for example:

**Sencha Touch** is a [Javascript Object-Oriented](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/) framework that lets you re-use a lot of your code, it supports the [Ext.util.Observable](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable) class for using custom event listeners, [Ext.util.MixedCollection](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection) for list iteration, and the [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) for very powerful data handling.

**JQuery Mobile** supports a whole rage of [touch handling events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html) that will allow you to easily provide functionality beyond basic DOM event functionality (click, hover etc), it also runs on jQuery which has support for custom event listeners using the [jQuery.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method, iteration using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and powerful AJAX calls using the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

In short, you are getting a lot more out of one of these frameworks when you use it, not just the interface. There is a lot of useful functionality in each framework that you would otherwise have to create yourselves from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Mobile you can just use the functionality you want as all the widgets are now decoupled:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Just pull the functionality you want from the Repo

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers were provided to this question so I won't step on their toes. I'll just say that I was in a very similar position as you. Designer created the screens, I hooked them up into jQuery Mobile. After much testing and many benchmarks I concluded jQM just wasn't there yet.

I chose Sencha Touch over a hodge podge and mashups of other frameworks and libraries simply because it does everything. You can even customize the UI to your liking, you'll just have to dive in to the CSS.

Now, I will point out a fundamental UI flaw... Your designer should be designing for the environment, meaning, they should have some sort of familiarity/understanding of the technology the design will be utilized in. That said, give your designer a break down of the chosen framework and how to design for it rather than against it. If the designer says no, then they are not the type of creative you need on your team. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have personally liked Sencha Touch. With latest version 2.4.1 support BlackBerry too. Its a very good bet when want to build apps to support all 4 popular mobile platforms (iOS/Android/Windows Phone/Blackberry). With Cordova packing Sencha Touch Hybrid apps give a very native like experience.

Also, http://mobileangularui.com/ is a very good alternative.

Comment: After building dozens of apps and exploring various options, now I am confidently say that IonicFramework (http://ionicframework.com/) is the best way to build Hybrid apps.